# Pyt TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python-3.x

This is my python program code but i cant write marks.txt im getting error like this its shows after x
Python Code

```
file = open('marks.txt','w')
s1marks=0
s2marks=0
index=int(input("index:"))
if index != -1:
    s1marks=str(input("subject1marks:"))
    s2marks=str(input("subject2marks:"))
    x=str("index is"+index+s1marks+s2marks)
    file.write(x)
    index=int(input("next index:"))
    file.close()
```

Error

index:10
subject1marks:8
subject2marks:5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 10, in 
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the category "*exactly what it says on the tin*"

change

```
x=str("index is"+index+s1marks+s2marks)
```

into

```
x = "index is" + str(index) + s1marks + s2marks
```

but that is not the only change I would make:

- You assigne an integer `0` to `s1marks` and `s2marks` variables, which then later you assign a `string` by taking an `input()`.
- You also convert an `input()` to `str()` explicitly, while the input is already an string by definition.
- You also take another `index` after writing to the file `file.write(x)`, but you don't loop around again, this is because you do not have a loop defined. Such as `while`.
- working with files, you should use `with`
- you don't need to assign variable `x` just for the `.write()` statement, unless you do something else with `x` later, which in this code you do not
- you need to do a new line character when writing to the file (this is an assumption I made, maybe you want the output file all on one line), which is `'\n'`
- you mix `"` and `'` in your code, best is to pick one and stick to it
- you don't insert spaces in your `write()` or `x=`, which you should to enhance readability of the output file.

Putting it all together:

```
with open('marks.txt', 'w') as openfile:
    index = int(input('index:'))
    while index > 0:
        s1marks = input('subject1marks:')
        s2marks = input('subject2marks:')
        openfile.write('index is ' + str(index) + ' ' + s1marks + ' ' + s2marks + '\n')
        index = int(input('index:'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert first the integer *index* to string. Python doesn't understand that you want to concatenate 4 strings as there is an integer :

```
x = "index is" + str(index) + s1marks + s2marks
```

I hope it helps,